# Display Image in gsp generated from class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, grails

I am showing the image path in the class file as below

```
String val;
val+= "<img src=/"PATH_TO_FILE/" alt=/"sometext/">"
```

and trying to load the image in gsp view in a div using jquery which is in the val variable.

Image is successfully found in the specified path, but the problem is that, image is not displaying in the gsp page.

I do not want to load image with the following Grails tag given below:

<`img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: image.name)}" alt="Grails"/>`

Is there any limitations in Grails using normal html img tag in Grails class to load image in view page?

Comment: there are no limitations of using the img tag, but what do you mean by mixin grails class and jquery into one context ? you want to get the image path wit ajax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backward slash rather than forward slash, like:

**Action:**

```
def test() {
    String val = "<img src=\"http://localhost:8080/formwizard/images/asd.png\" alt=\"sometext\">"
    [val: val]
}
```

**View:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divId").html('${val}');
    });
</script>
<div id="divId"></div>
```

**Note:-** If you are use the `"`(
        `String val = "<img src=\"http://localhost:8080/formwizard/images/asd.png\" alt=\"sometext\">"`) in action val string then use `'`(`'${val}'`) in scriptto get it and if use `'`(`"<img src='http://localhost:8080/formwizard/images/asd.png' alt='sometext'>"`) then use `"${val}"` in script.

***If you are using ajax then***

**Action:**

```
def test2() {
    String val = "<img src=\"http://localhost:8080/formwizard/images/asd.png\" alt=\"sometext\">"
    render val
}
```

**View:**

```
<script>
  function getImg() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "${createLink(controller: 'dashboard', action: 'test2')}",
      success: function (data) {
        $("#divId").html(data);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getImg()">Get Image</a>
<div id="divId"></div>
```

---

**EDIT......................................................................**

Change your code to:

```
def grailsLinkGenerator
def test2() {
    def basePath = grailsLinkGenerator.serverBaseURL
    String val = "<td><a href='adddd'><img width=\"50\" height=\"50\" src=" + basePath + "/images/repository/HrCrEmp/PIC_/0004-001.png alt=\"Fawkner Park\"></a></td>";
    render val
}
```

**NOTE:-** Works fine if image extension is `png` and if image extension is `jpg` then remove hyphen(`-`) sign from image name.

Comment: i tried but only alt attribute's text is displaying. In my controller i wrote like:  def basePath = System.properties['base.dir'];
        String val = "<td>" + "<a href='adddd'>" + "<img width=\"50\" height=\"50\" src="+basePath+"\\web-app\\images\\repository\\HrCrEmp\\PIC_\\0004-001.jpg\" alt=\"Fawkner Park\"></a></td>"; and called the action from ajax.

Comment: No success. It is generating the url like <img width="50" height="50" src=http://localhost:8080/HRMS/static/images/repository/HrCrEmp/PIC_/0004-001.jpg alt="Fawkner Park">, but my image is not available here. actually my image is in D: drive of my pc. Here is my image location D:\Rubel\Projects\W\hr\HRMS\web-app\images\repository\HrCrEmp\PIC_\0004-001.jpg. and when i paste this url into my address bar then image loads in the image viewer of my system

Comment: image source is generating like http://localhost:8080/HRMS/images/repository/HrCrEmp/PIC_/0004-001.jpg, but showing resource is not available. is there any " placing error or syntax error?

Comment: try to open this in the browser `http://localhost:8080/HRMS/images/repository/HrCrEmp/PIC_/0004-001.jpg`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40615/discussion-between-user1690588-and-rashedul-rubel)

Comment: After omitting the hyphen from the image file name, it worked. thanks